# Fragmented MP4 plays on my desktop but not any other computer?

Tags: mp4

I didn't ask this in the programming section because the code is fine I think its an OS problem or similar.

I have built a fragmented MP4 file (manually building atoms using c++) and it plays fine in Media Player on my desktop but my laptop and my mums laptop wont play it.

The mp4 video encoder I have used is Microsoft Media Foundation H264, all versions of Media Player are Windows 10 standard.  It also works with Windows Films and TV Player on my Desktop but again not on other computers.

Any ideas?  (any common pitfalls?)

Comment: What codec is the mp4 using? What settings are you using to encode it? What "media player" are you using? If you mean the Windows Media Player then what versions? What versions of Windows are you using? Have you tried any other media players. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1406119/edit) your question to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a pluggable system for media decoding filters/codecs. Windows ships with a number of codecs by default and third parties can and do add codecs to the list. There can be multiple implementations of the same codec.

I would guess that either your laptops don't have a codec installed for the video format you are using at all or there is something broken about your stream that some codecs cope with and others don't.